# Amazon Athena SQL: Group unique user id values by country

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, group-by, amazon-athena

1. Run AWS Athena SQL query against a single table for the total number of unique users per country.
2. Allow users to be present in multiple countries but only once per country.

This query returns unique users across all countries but does not allow a user to be unique to multiple countries:

```
select
    country_code,
    count(user_id) as unique_users_per_country
from
    user_data
group by
    country_code
order by
    country_code asc
```

Table structure:

```
|Column Name|Data Type|
|timestamp|bigint|
|user_id|string|
|country_code|string|
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a many-many relationship here - users can have multiple countries and countries of course can have multiple users. What I would do is create a table for Countries as well as Users and then have an intermediate table called CountryUsers where you reference the user_id and country_id as foreign keys. Then you'll have to join like so:

```
select users.id as userId, countries.id as countryId 
from users left join countryusers on countryusers.user_id = users.id
 left join countries on countryusers.country_id = countries.id order by countryId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried DISTINCT inside COUNT?

```
select
    country_code,
    count(distinct user_id) as unique_users_per_country
from
    user_data
group by
    country_code
order by
    country_code asc
```